# Able to log SOAP request and response but how to combine the input/output?

Tags: apache, soap, cxf

Hi there i am able to log input and output but i want to combine the incoming and outgoing xml so i can easily see the combined result? This would eliminate the task of manually digging out a log file.

Trying to accomplish this i have implemented 2 interceptors wich get the xml but i see now way to relate the outgoing xml to the incoming xml.

Any hints or tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use MessageExchange in the incoming interceptor:

Example:
In the inIntereptor -> message.getExchange().put("INPUT_LOG", your_long_string);
And in out interceptor -> something like message.getExchange().get("INPUT_LOG")

Then you have access to the original soap xml